# Some information about ,,addrinfo" in c?

Tags: c, sockets

i wonder if someone knows where the struct addrinfo is defined (header?). It seems to be used in socket - programming, but i never see it declared. I only see things like `struct addrinfo *head;` randomly used but addrinfo is never declared.

Then, in it (in addrinfo) there is a datatype `'socklen_t'`. Is that a datatype or what exactly is that?

Also in it there is `struct addrinfo *ai_next` which makes me wonder: for what is that usefull? In my understanding addrinfo stores information about how to connect with another socket and the `struct sockaddr *ai_addr`stores the exact address to which one desires to connect (i.e. the IP number and the port number in case of TCP/IP).
So with that said, shouldnt i only need exactly one addrinfo struct, beeing the one that stores my desired connection data? Why are there more?

Then: What is the last argument of `getaddrinfo` about? Its called `struct addrinfo **res` but i can not figure out, what that might be.

Allow me one last one, that might be pretty easy for you guys:

```
struct addrinfo hints = {
    .ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG,
    .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM,
    .ai_family = PF_UNSPEC
};
```

Am i correct when i say, hints is another struct of type addrinfo and the notation:

```
.ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG,
```

is actually short for:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
hints.ai_flags = AI....
```

Guys let me read what you know!
Love & respect to you all

Comment: [The `getaddrinfo` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) should tell you everything. Or find a tutorial of which there are plenty all over the Internet.

Comment: As for the "double pointer" it's a way of emulating pass-by-reference in C.

Comment: the double pointer is not the problem. The problem is, that i dont know what ,,res" is supposed to be.

Comment: A pointer to a variable that is a pointer. I.e. you define `struct addrinfo *res;` and then pass `&res`. The `getaddrinfo` function then makes `res` point a list of `addrinfo` structures. That is how pass by reference is emulated in C.

Comment: Please ask one question per post. You would get better reception of posts if you spend your love on research instead of vesting it on adding [fluff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addrinfo struct look like this:

```
struct addrinfo {
                 int              ai_flags;
                 int              ai_family;
                 int              ai_socktype;
                 int              ai_protocol;
                 socklen_t        ai_addrlen;
                 struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
                 char            *ai_canonname;
                 struct addrinfo *ai_next;
                };
```

Source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html

The `socklen_t` is a typedef of an int.

```
typedef _U32_TYPE int;
...
typedef socklen_t _U32_TYPE;
```

Source: https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.24/bits_2types_8h.html

The `ai_next` is used for create a linked list. I don't exactly know how to use this structure, but I think you might want to connect to multiple sockets, and not only one.

> The getaddrinfo() function allocates and initializes a linked list of addrinfo structures, one for each network address that matches node and service, subject to any restrictions imposed by hints, and returns a pointer to the start of the list in res.

So after calling `getaddrinfo()`, `*res` will be the first element of your linked list.

Finally, i'm not really sure if your syntax is correct, but this one is correct:

```
struct addrinfo hints = {
    .ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG,
    .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM,
    .ai_family = PF_UNSPEC
};
```

When you do that, you directly initialize those member, while when you do this:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
hints.ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
```

You create your structure (wich is filled with undefined content) and the you initialize the members.

So the result is the same, but the behaviour in memory is a bit different.

Comment: The OP declared `hints` using [designated initializers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Designated_initializers). Your declaration of `hints` is incorrect and will not compile.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, I edit that mistake